# Liferay webconten edit form don't have back link

Tags: liferay-6

I deploying a liferay 6.1 server. In my localhost server(for test), I went to controlpanel => webcontent => select a web content => choose 'edit'. It showed a edit form with a 'back' link at the header. And when I clicked 'publish' button or 'back' link, it redirected to the previous link. But in my real server, the edit form had no back link at the header. And when I clicked 'publish' button, it didn't redirect me to the previous page. So what are the differences between my test localhost and my real server? Configuration or error?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

In my case the name of the virutal host was not correct.

Try this:

Go to **Control Panel - Portalsettings - General**

Check the field **Virtual Host (This field is required!)**

Hope this helps.